# Counting rows from a subquery

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, select

Simple: I would like to count the number of rows from the sub-query. Note that *status* is whether the host is online or not.

#### Bad code

```
SELECT COUNT(ip_address) FROM `ports` (
    SELECT DISTINCT ip_address FROM `ports` WHERE status IS TRUE
)
```

#### Explained

The first query, when run on its own returns this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip_address FROM `ports` WHERE status IS TRUE
```

```
ip_address  
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.248
192.168.1.251
192.168.1.254
```

The second query run on its own returns this:

```
SELECT COUNT(ip_address) FROM `ports`
```

```
17
```

#### Question

I would like to know how to count that list of 5 IP addresses.

I have been looking online at possible solutions to this simple problem and just getting frustrated, so thought I'd ask the experts.

Comment: Sidenote, `WHERE status IS TRUE` can be shortened to `WHERE status`

Comment: personally I'd prefer `WHERE status IS TRUE` over `WHERE status` just so I can be sure the previous dev (past me) didn't make a mistake and I can see clearly what the intention is

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, how to count rows of a subquery, the syntax is as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (subquery) AS some_name;
```

The subquery should immediately follow the FROM keyword. (In MySQL it is also mandatory to assign a name to a subquery of this kind (it is actually called a *derived table*), which is why you can see the `AS some_name` following it.) The way you have written it, MySQL interprets your script as two independent queries, that is why you are getting two result sets.

So, since the subquery in your case is

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip_address FROM `ports` WHERE status IS TRUE
```

the complete query would look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ip_address FROM `ports` WHERE status IS TRUE
) AS derived;
```

But, [as Julien has suggested](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/133385/6965), you can rewrite your query just like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip_address) FROM `ports` WHERE status IS TRUE;
```

This way you do not need a subquery/derived table at all, because with the DISTINCT keyword the COUNT function will count only distinct occurrences of `ip_address` in the `ports` table.

Comment: FY:  worked just fine in Postgres 10 as well:  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (select * from bme_wk_umatch_ug where rdbname = 'xxx) as tocount;`  I had to use the OPs original concept because I am going to be counting the rows in an INTERSECT subquery.

Answer (score 10):

You must move the `DISTINCT` to the `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip_address) FROM `ports`;
```

This returns `5` because it only counts distinct values and the subquery is not needed anymore.

However this query returns `17` because there are 17 rows in the `ports`table:

```
SELECT COUNT(ip_address) FROM `ports`;
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bb89/1/0).

Sample data with 17 rows and 5 distinct IPs:

```
CREATE TABLE ports (ip_address varchar(20));

INSERT INTO `ports`(ip_address) VALUES
  ('192.168.1.1')
  , ('192.168.1.1')
  , ('192.168.1.1')
  , ('192.168.1.2')
  , ('192.168.1.2')
  , ('192.168.1.2')
  , ('192.168.1.2')
  , ('192.168.1.248')
  , ('192.168.1.248')
  , ('192.168.1.248')
  , ('192.168.1.248')
  , ('192.168.1.251')
  , ('192.168.1.251')
  , ('192.168.1.251')
  , ('192.168.1.254')
  , ('192.168.1.254')
  , ('192.168.1.254');
```

Comment: What about multiple nested tables rows are to be counted ?

Comment: Not sure what you need. You can ask a new question with your requirements on the main page.

Comment: I got it i was not using distinct field name and was not getting it

Answer (score 1):

No one pointed out the actual problem with the **`Bad code`** so: You need to name the inner `SELECT`'s output using `AS some_name`

```
SELECT COUNT(ip_address) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ip_address FROM `ports` WHERE status IS TRUE
) AS some_name
```

As mentioned already, best is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip_address) FROM `ports`;
```

---

## Why?

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363918/mysql-error-1248-42000-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias

On MySQL 5.7 you get ERROR `"[42000][1248] Every derived table must have its own alias"` without `AS some_name`. With it, it works.secs ago

Comment: Why does one "need to name the inner SELECT's output "?

Comment: @mustaccio, On MySQL 5.7 you get ERROR `"[42000][1248] Every derived table must have its own alias"` without `AS some_name`. With it, it works. Updated answer as well.